# Latest Xamarin forms ver3 above Error: Specified cast is not valid

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I m using Vs for mac: 7.5.1(Build 22). I try to build a Master Detail page with ListView binding to a simple class.

**Problem encountered:** `Specified cast is not valid`.

**In the code behind:** I have red underline for `InitializeComponent` as well as for the `ListView`. Why?

**In the SideMenu.xaml**: Do I need to add this?

```xml
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNavigationSideMenu"
```

Here the code:

```xml
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
                  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNavigationSideMenu;assembly=MyNavigationSideMenu"
                  x:Class="MyNavigationSideMenu.MySideMenu">

<MasterDetailPage.Master>

   <ContentPage Title="Menu">

    <Grid BackgroundColor ="Transparent">                
         <Grid.RowDefinitions>
             <RowDefinition Height ="200"/>
             <RowDefinition Height ="*"/>
         </Grid.RowDefinitions>

         <Grid>
          <Image Source="bg.png" Aspect="AspectFill" />
          <StackLayout Padding="0,20,0,0" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
          <Image Source="home.png" Aspect="AspectFit" WidthRequest="60" HeightRequest="60" />
          <Label Text="Xamarin Buddy" TextColor="White" FontSize="Large" />
          </StackLayout>
        </Grid>

        <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Spacing="15">
        <ListView x:Name ="navigationLV"
                  RowHeight ="60"
                  SeparatorVisibility ="None"
                  BackgroundColor ="#e8e8e8"
                  ItemSelected="OnMenuItemSelected">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                   <DataTemplate>
                      <ViewCell>
                          <StackLayout>
                           <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                      Orientation="Horizontal"
                                      Spacing="20">
                              <Image Source="{Binding Icon}"
                                     WidthRequest="30"
                                     HeightRequest="30"
                                     VerticalOptions="Center"/>

                              <Label Text="{Binding Title}"
                                     FontSize="Medium"
                                     VerticalOptions="Center"
                                     TextColor="Black"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                               <BoxView
                             HeightRequest="1"
                             BackgroundColor="Gray"/>     
                          </StackLayout>
                       </ViewCell>         
                   </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
         </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
     </Grid>  
    </ContentPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Master>

<MasterDetailPage.Detail>        
<NavigationPage>        
</NavigationPage>   
</MasterDetailPage.Detail>
```

here the code behind of SideMenu:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using MyNavigationSideMenu.MenuItems;

namespace MyNavigationSideMenu
{
  public partial class MySideMenu : MasterDetailPage  
  {
      public List<MasterPageItem> menuList { get; set; }

     public MySideMenu()
     {
          InitializeComponent();

          menuList = new List<MasterPageItem>();   

// Adding menu items to menuList and you can define title ,page and icon
menuList.Add(new MasterPageItem() { Title = "Home", Icon = "home.png", TargetType = typeof(HomePage) } );


         navigationLV.ItemsSource = menuList;

       // Initial navigation, this can be used for our home page
        Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(HomePage)));
    }

    private void OnMenuItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)        
   {
    var item = (MasterPageItem)e.SelectedItem;
    Type page = item.TargetType;
    Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(page));
    IsPresented = false;        

      }

    }
}
```

Comment: We can't read your code become of how it is formatted. Please fix your pasted code.

Comment: @Andres castro please help. I try my best to include the XML page with anchor tags. Please advise

Answer (score 0):

You need to check all these 3 steps:

1.Save the MySideMenu.xaml file & check red underline has gone.

2.Right click on MySideMenu.xaml & click on Properties & check Build Action should be set to "Embedded resource".

3.Add Try Catch for Initialize component in MySideMenu.xaml file & check which line the error is getting displayed.